# How can I drive a screw with an impact drill?

Tags: screws, drill

I bought a Bosch PSB 650 RE Impact Drill and I have some question about how to use it for driving screws. I know it's not its primary function but for a few screws here and there it should work. I have a magnetic adapter with a bit perfect for the screws, the drill has a variable speed control on the handle and by pressing the switch button deeper I increase the speed of rotation.

So here's my concern,

I tested with a screw, I pressed the switch button gently and it started to screw about half way then the screwing stopped, the drill sounded like it was spinning but it didn't had the power to insert the screw further. I pressed a little harder still the same, It sounded like it was turning but it didn't. To screw more I had to press harder on the handle to increase the speed and then it screwed all the way.

Is this a problem or this is how it should behave? Can the drill get damaged while it's working but not screwing cause it doesn't have enough power?

Comment: I use my impact driver for screws almost exclusively. I have driven many thousands of screws with mine and will drive many thousands more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is how it should work.  The drill is designed so that less pressure on the trigger means less power to the drill.  It *could* damage the driver if you were to keep it in that state of trying to turn and failing for an extremely extended period, but not if its momentary like you describe.

In short - good question but you're worrying too much. :)

Oh - yes - by the way - actually this *is* what it was designed for - exactly so.  It's designed to apply torque to bolts and screws and drill bits.

Comment: This isn't an impact driver. It's a [hammer drill](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Bosch-PSB-650-Hammer-Drill/dp/B003UES78A).

Answer (score 4):

I know an answer has been selected, but I think the people here are confusing an *impact driver* and an *impact drill*

If you look up the Bosch model he's talking about, he's referring to a hammer drill - evidently impact drill is what they call them in UK.

I haven't used that drill, but to me it seems strange that the motor would continue to spin while the chuck/bit came to a halt. In any drill I've used, the whole thing bogs right down when you are trying to turn something but it doesn't have enough power.

Comment: If the drill has torque settings it is possible.

Comment: Yeah I just looked up the model and it is indeed a hammer drill. There is not really a problem driving screws with a hammer drill, but I would turn the hammer action off to do so.

Comment: We call them hammer drills in the UK too.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have what we call in the USA a "hammer drill".  If so you should I would turn off the "hammer" (or "impact") function when driving screws.

I actually think what is happening is that the clutch is worked exactly as designed.  See the blog post we had on this site about it: http://diy.blogoverflow.com/2012/04/clutches-torque-and-you/

Comment: That model has no clutch.